# Overriding *.tpl.php in different directory

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How to override tpl files and keep them in separate sub-directory ? Some templates like core bartik keeps tpl files in template subdir. How to accomplish the same for custom own template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all of your templates files (*.tpl.php) in different subdirectories of your choice as long as they are in the "templates" directory of your theme. Drupal will find them without doing anything more, but you may need to flush caches for him to detect the new templates files.

Comment: Yes, it is working now, for some reason I did not flush caches.